# how to print a string with a variable by using echo command in the shell script

Tags: bash, shell, process, environment-variables, echo

I defined a shell variable in the terminal and then used the echo command to output a string with that variable and it worked fine in the terminal.

But when I use the same command in a shell script, the variable disappears without any output or error.

So, what's going on.

### terminal

```bash
$ NVM_USER=xgqfrms

$ echo $NVM_USER
xgqfrms

$ echo "string with a variable $NVM_USER"
string with a variable xgqfrms
$ echo string with a variable $NVM_USER
string with a variable xgqfrms
$ echo "string with a variable ${NVM_USER}"
string with a variable xgqfrms
```

[image]

### shell script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $NVM_USER
echo "string with a variable $NVM_USER"
echo string with a variable $NVM_USER
echo "string with a variable ${NVM_USER}"
```

[image]

I've searched and tried some solutions but still stuck.

### update

It works using a variable defined in shell scripts.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user=xgqfrms
echo "string with a variable ${user}"

# temp=$(echo $NVM_USER)
echo "string with a variable ${temp}"
```

[image]

Comment: The var hasn't been defined in the shell in which your script is running. If you're using cron, remember that the shell is a raw unprofiled shell.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you apply! In particular the `bash` and `shell` tags are mutually exclusive usually.

Comment: If you don't want to put the variable into the environment (since you explicitly say _shell variable_, not _environment variable_, set in in the shell script in the same way as you do it in the terminal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### The reasons why this question doesn't work.

1. when executing a shell script from a shell, it will auto create a new child shell, which can not visit the parent shell variables;
2. An environment variable is one that can be accessed in all the child or sub shells of the environment, however, a `local shell variable` can be accessed in only the shell in which it is defined.

```bash
# parent shell, set a shell variable for the current shell (parent shell)
$ NVM_USER=xgqfrms

# call a shell script, which will create a new shell (child shell)
$ ./test.sh

# So, the child shell can not access the parent shell variables ✅
```

### solutions

##### 1. when using the same terminal (only one `shell`)

use `export` to change a `shell variable` to a `environment variable`;

```bash
# terminal
$ export NVM_USER=xgqfrms
$ ./test.sh
```

[image]

As answered by [Gilles Quénot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77147179/5934465)

##### 2. when using two different terminals (two `shells` / `child processes`)

> `bash` demo

to make an environment variable persistent by defining a variable in the bash configuration file.

```bash
# terminal 1

# 1. add your export variable to the shell config file
$ sudo vim .bashrc
export NVM_USER=xgqfrms

# fresh the config
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

```bash
# terminal 2
$ ./test.sh
```

[image]

### `environment variable` vs `shell variable`

Variables can be classified into two main categories, environment variables, and shell variables.

`Environment variables` are variables that are available `system-wide` and are inherited by all spawned child processes and shells.

`Shell variables` are variables that apply only to the `current shell instance`. Each shell such as zsh and bash, has its own set of internal shell variables.

There are several commands available that allow you to list and set environment variables in Linux:

- `env` – The command allows you to run another program in a custom environment without modifying the current one. When used without an argument it will print a list of the current environment variables.
- `printenv` – The command prints all or the specified environment variables.
- `set` – The command sets or unsets shell variables. When used without an argument it will print a list of all variables including environment and shell variables, and shell functions.
- `unset` – The command deletes shell and environment variables.
- `export` – The command sets environment variables.

### refs

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/

Comment: Already answered, and your tag is `bash`, not `zsh`. What's the point? This is 2 different shells. You seems to discover shell and want to give response on how to do things in shell? Should be in your own wiki/web page.

Comment: My macOS default shell is zsh, but I have env set up to use bash in shell scripts. `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: The core point of using a config file is to support the use of multiple terminals. To prevent misleading, I removed the zsh demo.

Comment: The environment is accessible by child processes so it doesn't matter how you set it or where you access it (_you can set in zsh and use it in a bash script_)

Comment: You are right, I know that.

Comment: If you knew, this question wouldn't have been asked

Comment: I know that exporting an environment variable has the same effect whether I choose `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`. Don't get me wrong, it's different from my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell script should work independently of whether or not the variable is in the environment, set it **conditionally** in the shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
: ${NVM_USER:=xgqfrms}
```

In this way, the caller of the script can decide, whether he wants to go with the default value, i.e. call the script as

```
./test.sh
```

or override the value permanently in his own process, i.e.

```
export NVM_USER=katharina
...
./test.sh
...
./test.sh
```

or execute the script with one specific value for this variable:

```
NVM_USER=audrey ./test.sh # Not using katharina this time
```

In bash, a line of the form

```
V=E C
```

runs the command `C` in an environment, which is not just a copy of the environment of the parent process, but where the environment variable `V` is set to the value `E`. Hence in this example, `NVM_USER` is set to the value *audrey* in the environment of the process running `test.sh`, without affecting the setting of this variable in the calling process.

Comment: the `default value` is fine, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: @xgqfrms : Well, the only question I found is "what's going on", and the answer is that you did not use any of the three possibilities I am explaining here. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: I just want to know the reason behind it and not just make it work. You didn't explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: You copied it wrongly: You need to remove  the `$`.  But I can add an explanation.

Comment: @xgqfrms : Explanation added ....

Answer (score -1):

You need to `export` the variable:

```
export NVM_USER=foobar
```

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "string with a variable $NVM_USER"
```

If you run this in another environment, you can create a source file:

```
export NVM_USER=foobar
```

then

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source source-file.sh    
echo "string with a variable $NVM_USER"
```

---

```
$ help export
export: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
    Set export attribute for shell variables.
    
    Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
    executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.
    
    Options:
      -f    refer to shell functions
      -n    remove the export property from each NAME
      -p    display a list of all exported variables and functions
    
    An argument of `--' disables further option processing.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or NAME is invalid.
```

Comment: Are exported variables globally scoped? When I use another terminal to set the variable, it doesn't seem to work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gnk7.png

Comment: Then, use the solution I gave. Use `source env.sh` where `env.sh` is the variables declarations. The variable declaration is not _magic_ nor _global_ in the sense you expect, to be global and everywhere, you need to declare the variable in `/etc/environment` by example

Comment: I didn't use an `env.sh` file, just created it in the terminal as my screenshot shows. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gnk7.png

Comment: It cannot works this way, no

Comment: all right, thanks a lot.